# Afraid of confidentiality agreement; will I be breaking it?

Tags: non-disclosure-agreement, confidentiality

I signed a confidentiality agreement with a company that was for an unpaid "job". I quit with them and now had some innovative ideas I had to share with them on past projects I couldn't do before.

Since I don't have the company e-mail, I can only e-mail the person who works there using insecure communication. I want to share my ideas but am reluctant to use any viable method of communication like e-mail, phone because I'm afraid I'll somehow violate the CDA even post termination of employment because I'm leaking "good" ideas on the web.

I'm also highly suspicious of their honor and finances and doubt they'll pay me for my efforts to bring new ideas to them-which doesn't mean that I'm doing this for money but I seriously like some money.  *What should I do?*

Comment: If they didn't pay you when you were doing work for them, what makes you think they would pay you for some ideas?

Comment: So, what does that agreement state on it's extent and length of duration? I suppose it was also a legally binding agreement

Comment: I can't remember and can't show you because it's part of the CDA>

Comment: What was the (general) nature of the "job"? Were you there in the capacity of something like: bringing/sharing ideas with them?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm also highly suspicious of their honor and finances and doubt they'll pay me for my efforts to bring new ideas to them-which doesn't mean that I'm doing this for money but I [really want] some money.

To recap into bullet points:

1. They have low honor
2. You don't expect payment
3. You aren't doing it for the money
4. ...but you "[really want] some money"

> *What should I do?*

Your NDA is irrelevant.

Keep your ideas to yourself.
Move on with your life.

Comment: i think that is the correct answer. OP's situation is weird and NDA is the least of their problem

Comment: +1 exactly! why would you give the company, who used you as slave labor, an idea that could make them more money. they made enough off you by not paying you. personally I would be trying to sell it to a competitor that actually values their employees enough to pay them

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do?

You should check the agreement you signed and look for what it states on the duration or length of its validity.

Then you will know if you are still under its effect or not, and know how to proceed (I doubt it was forever, though, but you better check what is written on it).

> I want to share my ideas but am reluctant to use any viable method of communication like e-mail, phone because I'm afraid I'll somehow violate the CDA even post termination of employment because I'm leaking "good" ideas on the web.

Regarding this, if one is under a NDA or confidentiality agreement, sharing it by *any* means (not only the "viable" ones) would be a violation to the contract, so you seeking alternate ways to communicate won't prevent you from breaking the contract, *if any or still valid*.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a non disclosure agreement prevents you from telling others what your employer (or whatever their relationship is to you) does, did, or told you. It doesn't prevent you telling them things in a way that others can overhear. Read yours to be sure.

That said, just because you have only an insecure way to talk doesn't mean you have to blurt out all your secrets on the insecure channel. You can email or call someone and say

> I'd like to talk about some ideas I have for [vague terminology like "your mobile applications"]. Should we meet in person or set up a secure channel?

And if you'd like to be paid for the ideas, or for implementing them, or for joining a team that is implementing them, you can  say so before presenting the ideas. You should know it is very very rare to be paid for ideas. Usually the closest you get to payment is that you get hired (or contracted) to implement them. I suppose it's possible your ideas are so amazing someone would want to  license them -- but people tend to license products, solutions, and technology, not ideas for how someone else might create a product, a solution, or a technology.